# How to get an unabbreviated version of a CLPlacemark administrative area

Tags: ios, swift, cllocationmanager, clplacemark

When I call this delegate method:

```
func displayLocationInfo (placemark: CLPlacemark) {
    
    self.locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
    
    // Find current state
    self.currentState = placemark.administrativeArea
}
```

The administrative area returns, for example, CA instead of California. Is there anyway I can make the administrative area return the full name instead of the abbreviated version. Any help will be appreciative!

Comment: Nope, there is no way to set this. Per Apple Docs:  "The string in this property can be either the spelled out name of the administrative area or its designated abbreviation, if one exists."

Answer (score 1):

Nope, there is no reliable way to retrieve this information. Per [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/clplacemark/1423628-administrativearea):

> The string in this property can be either the spelled out name of the administrative area or its designated abbreviation, if one exists. If the placemark location is Apple’s headquarters, for example, the value for this property would be the string “CA” or “California”.

(Answer extracted from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30921843/how-to-get-an-unabbreviated-version-of-a-clplacemark-administrative-area#comment49883149_30921843) comment)